# trying to give a variable to ifstream in c++

Tags: c++, file

im new to c++ and trying to put a variable in this line : ifstream studentPaper(paper);
ill pass paper to this function and want to use it there. string paper has my files location (/name/file.txt)

if i put my file name there i dont get any errors = ifstream studentPaper("/name/file.txt");
but when i save my files location in to a string and give string to it ill get error = ifstream studentPaper(paper);

how can i do that without getting errors

```
void matchGrades(string paper) {
string aa= "asd";
ifstream studentPaper(paper);
ifstream base("base.txt");
int grade=3;
while ((!studentPaper.eof()) && (!base.eof())) {
    string l1,l2;
    getline(studentPaper,l1);
    getline(base,l2);
    if(l1==l2){
       grade += 3;
    } else {
        grade -= 3;
    }
}
studentPaper.close();
base.close();
cout << grade;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `ifstream studentPaper(paper.c_str())`.

Also if your file is located where your main.cpp is you won't need to specify the path. Something like this:

```
string studentFile = "student_file.txt";
```

Based on the information provided. If you are still getting an error please post it so that I can adjust my answer.

Comment: No problem. I am glad that I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that You have to use removed string parameter `"/name/file.txt"` 
 because parameter split space.